# Login issues with 2 shops

Tags: magento-1.9, login, cookie, admin-login

I've got 2 shops:

- shop.example.com
- dev.shop.example.com (dev version)

If I login on first shop I can't logon on the 2nd anymore...
It's a cookie problem.

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like '%cookie%';
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------+----------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                                   | value          |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------+----------------+
|       370 | default |        0 | web/default/cms_no_cookies             | enable-cookies |
|       373 | default |        0 | web/cookie/cookie_lifetime             | 3600           |
|       374 | default |        0 | web/cookie/cookie_path                 | NULL           |
|       375 | default |        0 | web/cookie/cookie_domain               | NULL           |
|       376 | default |        0 | web/cookie/cookie_httponly             | 1              |
|       377 | default |        0 | web/cookie/cookie_restriction          | 0              |
|       383 | default |        0 | web/browser_capabilities/cookies       | 1              |
|      1977 | default |        0 | admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime | 10000          |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What are the correct settings for the cookie_path and cookie_domain?

Answer (score 0):

**Cookie path** should be `/`
**Cookie domain** should be `shop.example.com` for live and `dev.shop.example.com` for dev system

Answer (score 0):

You should use different root domains to avoid the login problem.This [blog post](http://blog.philwinkle.com/i-cant-login-to-magento-admin/) explains about this particular issue in detail.